# Eclipse Cdt Indexer - how to locate syntax errors and unresolved names

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

Using:

- Eclipse 4.4.0 (Luna) with Cdt 8.4.0.201406111759
- native gcc / g++ and also cross gcc-arm
- C/C++ project with external makefile

I'd spend some effort to setup the cdt indexer properly (including automatic discovery of the gcc-arm builtin specs, build output discovery et cetera).

When reindexing the whole project, the Error Log View shows something like this:

```
Indexed 'Stm-Workbench' (41 sources, 180 headers) in 3,58 sec: 13.921 declarations; 34.120 references; 0 unresolved inclusions; 1 syntax errors; 9 unresolved names (0,019 %)
```

I now want to check where the remaining syntax errors and unresolved names are located / referenced from.

I surely know how to locate the references of unresolved inclusions (Project → C/C++ Index → Search for unresolved includes).

But how to locate the other potential issues?

Of course, I could open every single source file of my whole project because when opening a file I see the in the problems view. But I hope there may be a less dumb way.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called [Problems View](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_problems_view.htm). It enables you to find the location of the issues at hand

[image]

Comment: Of course, I know the Problems View. But after `Index → Rebuild`, the Problems View is empty. As I wrote in my question, the issue locations became visible in the Problems View when I open the related file.